# looping through an array from split

Tags: vbscript

I what to show some companies from my MySQL database.
The first companies I get, I store the companyId in a string like this:

```
companyList = companyList & "|" & rs1("supplier_id")
```

Then I get some more companies and I only want to show these companies if they are not already in my `companyList`. So I split my list and loop through it like this:

```
companyList = Split(companyList, "|")

already_shown = 0                                 
For Each x In companyList
    If x = CInt(rs1("companyId")) Then
       already_shown = 1
    End If
Next
```

My problem is that even if a companyId is in the list it is still getting shown. Why is that?

I have tried this:

```
If CInt(x) = CInt(rs1("companyId")) Then
```

But I got an error. My list contains only integers.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Your question/code doesn't really match up.  Are you missing some code?

Comment: I only took the relevant code. What are you missing?

Comment: You wrote you store the companyId in a string, but the first line of code uses `supplier_id`, not `companyId`. Please share the entire code, including assigning to `rs1` and `companyList` variables.

Comment: Please *show* the error you were getting. Did you check the actual value and type of both `x` and `rs1("companyId")` when the error occurred?

Comment: Thank you both.
I found the error. For some reason the first x was empty. So now my problem is solved :-)

Comment: @SanneFaurholt The first x is empty because of how you built the string.  The first time you update `companyList`, you are setting it to `companyList & "|" & rs1("supplier_id")` - and the first time you do this, `companyList` is blank.  This means your string starts with a `|` char.  When you then `Split` on this character, the resulting array has an empty first element as the method expects the `|` to only exist between elements.  Same if your string ends with the `|`, you'd have an empty element on the end of the array.